# Null checker null safety error how i can stopped it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, angular-dart

I'm designing a mobile Application ,it looks like "WhatsApp" I initiate class called "chat model"

when i run app it gives me "Null safety error or null checker" I want to display the name of person

please advice me to solve this problem

```
 class Chat Model {     */my code in chat model class
  String? name;
  String? icon;  
  bool? is group;
  String? time;
  String? current message;
  Chat Model(
  {this.name, this. icon, this.is group, this. time, this. current message});
}


     


       class chatpage extends StatefulWidget {  */ my code in chat page 
       const chatpage({super.key});

        @override
      State<chatpage> createState() => _chatpageState();
  }

  // ignore: camel_case_types
  class _chatpageState extends State<chatpage> {
   List<ChatModel> chats = [
    ChatModel(
    name: "Ahmed omar",
    icon: "person.svg",
    isgroup: false,
    time: "10:00",
    currentmessage: "Hi Ahmed"),
    ChatModel(
    name: "Hussien Mohamed",
    icon: "person.svg",
    isgroup: true,
    time: "10:00",
    currentmessage: "Hi everyone"),
    ChatModel(
    name: "Hussien omar",
    icon: "person.svg",
    isgroup: false,
    time: "10:00",
    currentmessage: "Hi Hussien"),
    ChatModel(
    name: "Hussien omar",
     icon: "person.svg",
     isgroup: true,
     time: "10:00",
     currentmessage: "Hi everyone"),
      ];
           
                                  */ error here

                  Text(
                    widget.chatModel!.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.5,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
```

Comment: `widget.chatModel!` forces the type system to assume that `chatModel` isn't null. If it **is** null, then this will result in an error. Either remove the `?` from `chatModel?` so that it can never be null or make sure that it isn't null before trying to use it.

Comment: show to me error when I removed ? mark give me another solution

Comment: There is no other solution. Those are your two options. `chatModel` needs to not be null, so either make sure it isn't null or make it so it can't possibly be null. If you are unsure how to use null safety in Dart, I'd recommend [reading up on the subject](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).